# Submitting a form using jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have this form that loads rows of data in a table format using form. Than user updates some of the amount and submits the form. Form works fine, I don't know how to submit the updated values from html page to jQuery function.

```
<div id="Sales">
    <script id="salestTemp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
        <form id="salesForm" action="">
            <table class="" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="label"><a href="">Name<span class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a></th>                
                        <th class="label"><a href="">$ Amount<span class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a></th>                  
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each items}}
                    <tr class="">
                        <td>{{=name}}</td>
                        <td>$&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="{{=id}}" id="Amount" value='{{=Amount}}' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}  
                    <tr>
                        <input type="submit" class="" id="submit" name="" value="Save" />
                    </tr>
                </tbody>           
            </table>                 
        </form>
    </script
</div>
```

I am using following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        alert("inside");
        $.ajax {......};
    });
});
```

When I hit submit it doesn't even hit .click function. Anyone knows how to fix this or where to look? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has a broken closing tag:

```
</script
</div>
```

Consider binding to the submit event:

```
$("#salesForm").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("inside");
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` will prevent the form from submitting, you can then use ajax to submit the form.

Here is an example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/Jbbhe/2/

Answer (score 0):

It has hit the click function check the error console in the browser..
and script tag is not ended properly ""..

And y have you put the form content inside script tag???

Answer (score -1):

Just bind your form to submit

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#salesForm_form').bind('submit',function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Or

```
$('#salesForm_form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    /* Validations go here */
    this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
});
```

Comment: "With type Submit onlick won't work i guess, you need to keep type as button." - See http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/Jbbhe/3/